# String formatting in a loop

Tags: python, string, loops, formatting

I've got a directory full of JPG photographs. I want to take the file names of those photographs and end up with the following being printed:

```
<description>Test. <![CDATA[<img src='.
/files/fantaWP.jpg]>]]></description>
```

**The file name is a variable**. I've tried my very best below and i'm nearly there, but I end up with the following output:

```
<description>Test. <![CDATA[<img src='.
/files/['fantaWP.jpg', 'icon', 'p1.JPG', 'p2.JPG', 'p3.jpg', 'p4.jpg']>]]></description>
```

Here is my code:

```
photofileName = []

path='C:\Users\Simon\Desktop\Dir\pics' 

dirList=os.listdir(path)
for fname in dirList:
    photofileName.append(fname)

print photofileName


photoVar = [x for x in photofileName]

itemsInListOne = 3

iterations = itemsInListOne

num = 0

while num < iterations:
        num = num+1
        print ("\<description>Test. <![CDATA[<img src='./files/{}'>]]></description>\n".format(photoVar))
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should be enough if I understand you correctly.

```
for fname in os.listdir(path):
    print("\<description>Test. <![CDATA[<img src='./files/{}'>]]>=</description>\n".format(fname))
```

Example:

```
>>> path = "/home/msvalkon/Pictures/Sample Album"
>>> for fname in os.listdir(path):
...     print("\<description>Test. <![CDATA[<img src='./files/{}'>]]>=</description>\n".format(fname))
...     
... 
\<description>Test. <![CDATA[<img src='./files/Costa Rican Frog.jpg'>]]>=</description>

\<description>Test. <![CDATA[<img src='./files/Pensive Parakeet.jpg'>]]>=</description>

\<description>Test. <![CDATA[<img src='./files/Boston City Flow.jpg'>]]>=</description>

>>>
```

And the content of the path..

```
msvalkon@Lunkwill:~/Pictures/Sample Album$ ll
total 1208
drwxrwxr-x 2 msvalkon msvalkon   4096 Apr 19  2012 ./
drwxr-xr-x 7 msvalkon msvalkon  28672 Jan  3 18:27 ../
-rw-rw-r-- 1 msvalkon msvalkon 339773 Dec 13  2009 Boston City Flow.jpg
-rw-rw-r-- 1 msvalkon msvalkon 354633 Dec 13  2009 Costa Rican Frog.jpg
-rw-rw-r-- 1 msvalkon msvalkon 480098 Dec 13  2009 Pensive Parakeet.jpg
```